# Contact info for patent holder

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [US20130000482](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130000482)

How do I contact the patent holder, Joseph C. Kopchick?

Thank you

Chris
bud.weiserstein@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

He may be an employee of the assignee:

GM Global Technology Operations LLC
300 Renaissance Ctr.,
Detroit, MI 48243,
United States
Phone: 1-313-665-3988

Use the public PAIR at the USPTO to contact the attorney/agent of record to see if they can contact the inventor for you:

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

VIVACQUA LAW, PLLC

3101 East Eisenhower Parkway

Suite 1

ANN ARBOR MI 48108

There are at least a dozen attorneys listed on the application with phone numbers.